# Exception Processing Message 0x0000005 -Unexpected parameters

Tags: operating-system

This Error is occuring while opening taskbar setting through taskbar:

[image]

While Clicking it this Error pops-up

[image]

There Are Some **Following Steps** I tried to solve this proble:

1. **Runing out "sfc / scannow**" command prompt as administarator
2. **Diabling "Window Error Reporting Problems**"  **from Services.msc**
3. After doing that this **Error is Visible on the Screen. otherwise the Taskbar Window is Automatically Closing**
4. **From the** Task Manager I Restarts the **Explorer**
5. Even I Do  **Windows Memory  Diagonsis**  as adminstrator I while when the Restart is complete No change is Visible
6. **But When I tried to Open** this Taskbar setting from the  **Window Setting**  from  **personalize** under it their is Taskber tab available So, When I Click on that , The Window Open and Terminate automatically.

After doing this all nothing change is their

Now, I am with this Error:

So plzz anyone Help to solve this Error

Comment: You should post it on: https://superuser.com/